# Simplify easy disjunctive normal form(DNF).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So, I am struggling with the last part of my expression, where I got the :

[image: Expression] .

I made a Karnough map and it clearly shows that the last ($x_2$ inversion, $x_3$, $x_4$ inversion)  is not needed at all, but I have no idea no how get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically an application of the Consensus Theorem. Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\overline x_1 x_3 \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4 \vee  \overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4
&= \overline x_1 x_3 \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4 \vee  (\overline x_1 \vee x_1)\overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4 \\
&= \overline x_1 x_3 \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4 \vee  (\overline x_1 \overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4 \vee x_1\overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4) \\
&= (\overline x_1 x_3 \vee \overline x_1 \overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4) \vee (x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4 \vee x_1\overline x_2 x_3 \overline x_4) \\
&= \overline x_1 x_3(1\vee \overline x_2 \overline x_4) \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4(1\vee x_3) \\
&= \overline x_1 x_3(1) \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4(1) \\
&= \overline x_1 x_3 \vee x_1 \overline x_2 \overline x_4 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks so much, you forgot to add the 4 variable part, but I will add it myself, no problem. Thanks so much!